# FileMaker - Getting Data From Another Table with Multiple Field Restrictions

Tags: filemaker, relationships

I can't think of a better title, so feel free to make a suggestion once you understand the issue.

I was given a table to work with that I need to call from another table:

Name
Month
Type
Value

For each record in the main table I need to pull one "Value" that corresponds to it. What it is will be determined by all three of the other fields. So for example, if a record in the main table is:

Name:
Google

Date:
3\17\2016

Type:
M

Then I need to pull the value for the record in the other table where the Name is "Google", the month is "3", and the type is "M".

I was able to do this successfully (if slowly) using an ExecuteSQL command in a calculation field, with a ton of nested If statements for the names (I have yet to figure out how to input the record's data directly into the ExecuteSQL statement, it breaks when I try). I would prefer to just grab the data directly. I can't switch over to the other layout because I need to see all of the records at once. I can't do a simple relationship because there isn't a real relationship, it's like there are three foreign keys working in tandem and I only know how to use one to call the data.

Any idea on how to do this more simplistically?

Some ideas I've had but not sure if it will work:

Using a calculation field as a related field to dynamically point to the row by code (concatenate the three relevant fields into a type of code). Not sure if you can connect two tables by a calculation field.

Doing that same thing when calling the data into the table in the first place, adding a code to create a single primary key.

Here are my relationships:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't do a simple relationship because there isn't a real
>   relationship, it's like there are three foreign keys working in tandem
>   and I only know how to use one to call the data.

Simply define a relationship with three predicates - i.e. three pairs of match fields.

Comment: You can do that? One field is a date field and the other is a month field, so how can I get that to work? There are dates assigned to each main record, but the relevant data I'm trying to pull it determined by month (so all the records in march have the same data (per name and type). Should I just create a separate field in the main table to pull the month?

Comment: For the month, you will need to add a calculation field in the table where the date is and use that as the match field instead of the date. That's irrelevant to your main question. -- Note that when matching by month only, you will get records in *any* year.

Comment: So far, it does not appear to be working. I have matched up the three fields, they all match types (even the calculation). No values appear.

Comment: Post a screenshot of your relationship setup. -- Keep in mind that an exact match is required in all three predicates: if you have so much as a trailing space in one of values, it won't match.

Comment: Relationship setup posted.

Comment: Seems fine on the surface. Now try it with one predicate at a time, and see which one is the deal breaker.

Comment: It looks like it's the GroupName. I think I have a work around.

Comment: Okay, got it working. Still a little wonky, but thanks a lot.